# How do I implement the sleep function in my for loop correctly? (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sleep

I'm trying to make my code print something to the screen, then wait 1 second, then go around the for loop and print it again 21 times. It works when I do this in Windows in CodeBlocks by using #include  and then Sleep(1000). But when I'm doing it on my Ubuntu VM by using #include  and sleep(1), everything disappears from my terminal for 21 seconds then all appears at once. I think I'm using the wrong function or something.

Any ideas?

This is the code in Ubuntu terminal which ends up removing everything already on my terminal, waits 21 seconds then just prints "Hello" 21 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()

{
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello");
        sleep(1);           
    }

}
```

This is the code in Windows which prints "Hello" every second for 21 seconds therefore printing 21 Hello's on my screen over 21 seconds. Which is what I'm trying to achieve in my Ubuntu VM.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    int main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            printf("Hello");
            Sleep(1000);
        }

        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Replace `printf` with `puts`.

Comment: Voting to close: OP admits the MCVE they provided is different from the actual problem they are solving, suggest new question. To quote OP: `I tried adding the fflush(stdout); like you suggested, but it doesn't work for my code - probably because I'm using mvprintw (from ncurses) instead of printf`

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX, process streams buffer - they accumulate I/O and do not "flush" to the underlying device immediately on write, per default.  So - you need to flush the stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()

{
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);           
    }

}
```

It would also work if you output a newline '\n' after "Hello", I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` output is buffered - which means, it is not guaranteed to appear on the screen immediately. Rather, it appears when one of the following happens:

- when the buffer becomes full, - at which time the old contents of buffer is displayed to the screen and the buffer is cleared fresh for the new output - this is called *buffer flushing*
- when the application terminates - which forces flushing of all the `printf` buffers, and this is what you see on the screen
- When buffer is flushed by the programmer.

The last case is most interesting for you, and there are two ways you can do this - either include `\n` (new line) control character in your string, like

```
 printf("Hello\n");
```

or call `fflush` for stdout stream, like

```
 printf("Hello");
 fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use another function to achieve the same thing? I tried adding the `fflush(stdout);` like you suggested, but it doesn't work for my code - probably because I'm using `mvprintw` (from ncurses) instead of `printf`. I thought I would be able to apply the same solution but apparently not. Is there something else I can use instead of sleep?

Comment: @Sawy3r it would be of tremendous help for you and people answering your question if your MCVE is actually MCVE. You now have two answers which took your question on it's face value. I suggest you ask a **different** question with proper MCVE.